# Xcode 4.2 Snowleopard Master-Detail Application troubleshooting

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, osx-snow-leopard

I am a noob at iOS application development.
I trying to create "UITableView -> to Detail View" application.
And found out "Master-Detail Application" project in the project template.

Then I tried it out.  Then the problem came.
I had a dynamic table view, so I have to make the detail view look dynamic too.
Like this :

```
Table View      Detail View
  Item A            Item A is an <item_A_description>, with <item_A_summary>
  Item B            Item B is an <item_B_description>, with <item_B_summary>
  Item C            Item C is an <item_C_description>, with <item_C_summary>
```

the problem is, after I go back to the table (list) view using back button menu,
then I choose the again the item from different row of the list, then the Detail View doesn't changed to selected Item value.
I did pass the value using (MasterView) -> initWithNibName -> (DetailView)
My environment : XCode 4.2 for SnowLeopard, iOS SDK 5

**Updated**
After I check the log, the parameter value did passed with the correct value. But the IBOutlet of UIlabel that I set didn't change it's value.
This is  my code :

MasterViewController.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TheItems *a = [data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if (!self.detailViewController) {
            self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil withItemId:(NSString *)a.itemId];
        }
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
        [self.detailViewController release];
    }
}
```

DetailViewController.h :

```
@interface metapsDetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
{
    NSString *itemId;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * detailItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *itemId;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withItemId:(NSString *)itemId;
```

DetailViewController.m :

```
@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;
@synthesize itemId;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withItemId:(NSString *)itemId
{


    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Detail", @"Detail");
        self.itemId = itemId;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.detailItem.text = self.itemId;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only create the detailViewController when it doesn't exist. The Item you give to the detailViewController is in your init, so the item will only be set once. You should add a method (or property) to your detailViewController where you can set the item, so that it can change your detailViewController when you get new data.

Edit: Implement something like this:

```
@synthesize itemId = _itemId;

-(void)setitemId:(NSString*)itemId{

    if(_itemId != itemId)
    {
        [_itemId release];
        _itemId = [itemId retain];
        self.detailItem.text = _itemId;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yeah, actually I tried using a property in DetailViewController, and pass the value on MasterViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath via that property `self.detailViewController.itemId  = a.itemId;` ... But it also didn't work

Comment: You should implement the label change as well in the detailViewController, look at edit.

Comment: Thanks, I give it a try of this.

Comment: I have a question about this, how about if I have a lot of label or UIImage, should I implement that method for all ui elements ?

Comment: Instead of giving an itemId to the detailViewContoller you should give it the entire object.

Comment: I'm sorry actually I getting confused of it... I tried to implements that, but I don't know where to put it. Do you have any example complete source ^^; ?  .. And why I just giving Id because in detail view I need to load Information from the server before the detail view appear.

Comment: The code is in the DetailViewController. There you have a property itemId. This method is just in the implementation, it's a custom implementation of the setter of the itemId property.

You'll only need the itemId then, once you get the itemId you start loading all data you need. So instead of setting the label you'll have to call the method to start loading the item.

Comment: So there are the setters of property. I'm sorry still have a point to confirm, where I should call this setters ?

Comment: In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the MasterViewController.